# How can I extract all the words after a symbol and before space by Regular Expression

Tags: regex

For instance, how can I extract '@dog @cat' from 'rabbit @dog bird @cat fish' by regular expression?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is straight forward, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regular expression (Using `\w` to match alpha-numeric/underscore character):

```
@\w+
```

Javascript example:

```
'rabbit @dog bird @cat fish'.match(/@\w+/g)
// => ["@dog", "@cat"]
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, You're right. Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex  ::

```
/@(dog|cat)\b/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yO2cZ0/1